# Keeping a HttpClient alive in Android

Tags: android, httpclient, android-asynctask, android-service

I am developing an android application which fetches data from a stateful web-server. Hence a httpsession is maintained.

Currently I have developed a singleton class in my android-app which is responsible for all the communication with the web-server.

My concern is that if there is no valid reference to this class (my httpclient) than the garbage collector may mark & sweep this class hence killing the session.

Is there any way I can keep this class alive? Do we have somthing similar to ServletContext or HttpSession in android where we can keep the reference of my httpclient?

Comment: did you find the answer to your problem. I have the same question and i dont find anything about this. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can look around for solutions with "HttpClient" inside Android Services or AsyncTask...

A couple of links:

[Not with HTTPCLIENT, but nice to get to know Services.](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/60.html)

[HttpClient as Background Service...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5682632/android-httpclient-as-a-backgroundservice)

[And this guys says "keep-alive" does not work on mobiles? Havent tried it, actually...](http://www.anddev.org/networking-database-problems-f29/uable-to-pool-connections-using-apache-http-client-t48576.html#p87356)