# connect application with website

Tags: android

I want to implement an application that connected with a site, if I upload files in this site ,it will directly appear in the application and will notify the user for new uploading files
then the user can download the files from the application
 My question is What are the main steps to start implementing the application.

Answer (score 1):

try [google cloud messaging](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html).There are sample codes that can help you
....

Answer (score 1):

If your app is just rendering the content that comes from a website, you might want to consider the option of just having a customized web interface and access it from the web browser. It makes it much simpler to update the content, layout etc.

Another option is to use a WebView to create an app that lets you embed web content directly. Have a look here: http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/overview.html

If these don't suit your need, you may have to create a regular standalone android app that talks to your web site. Then you will need to define some API/messaging for this communication. The specifics will depend on what exactly your application does, but the messaging could be as simple as a few http GET requests, assuming you have a webserver running on the other side. E.g., you could call an http GET to fetch the list of files you want to download. And then to download each file, you can issue separate GET requests on the appropriate urls. You can have an android service running in the background that does periodic http GETS to refresh the content.

See this link on running a background service to do http operations:
[Android - httpclient as a backgroundservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5682632/android-httpclient-as-a-backgroundservice)