# Android - is it possible to run DefaultHTTPClient in the service?

Tags: android, service, httpclient

I run DefaultHttpClient in the Android service, but I cannot get any result even though error.
Is it possible? Through surfing, I found make HTTPClient as service, but I cannot find call HTTPClient in the service. Looking forward help.

Comment: DefaultHttpClient is unware of the context where it runs. You can run it where do you like

Comment: yes it's possible post your relevant code then we will trying to help you more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked up how to use the HTTP Client, Post, and Response in Java? Here is a basic example, as one might use in an AsyncTask doInBackground function:

```
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;


//in doInBackground() or other thread outside of main
InputStream myStream;
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url_select);

List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);

try {
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("currentUser", currentUserVar));
    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

    myStream = response.getEntity().getContent();

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) { e.printStackTrace(); 
} catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can "run DefaultHttpClient" in an Android service. You can get results (response code, response, etc) back to your other components (Activity, etc) in several ways.

You can use a [ResultReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/ResultReceiver.html).

Or, you can use a service bus, like Otto (this is a lot easier if you are willing to learn a little about the bus and set it up, and it comes in handy in many places, not just services).

To really help though you'll need to make the question a little more clear. Is your Service already working and making HTTP requests and you just need to get the result to other components, or can you not get DefaultHTTPClient to work at all, service or not?

Also if you don't want to deal with handling the threading on your own, you should look into [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html). It's often an excellent candidate for something like an "HTTP client in a service."

This question has more general info: [Android - httpclient as a backgroundservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5682632/android-httpclient-as-a-backgroundservice)